# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Here is the error]
I've created constructors in another class but it ain't working.

Here is the code...

```
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return !snapshot.hasData
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return ProductItem(
                  documentSnapshot: data,
                  id: data.id,
                  isFavourite: data['isFavourite'],
                  imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
                  productName: data['productName'],
                  productPrice: data['productPrice'],
                );
              },
            );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: hi may you provide full code?

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: what is snapshot.data.docs[index]?  is this returing array

Comment: yeah it returns the data as an array

Comment: List<DocumentSnapshot> data = snapshot.data.docs[index];

Comment: Did you try this

Comment: QueryDocumentSnapshot...kinda similar to that right?

Comment: do data.value['isFavourite'] instead of data['isFavourite']

Comment: @Uni still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return !snapshot.hasData
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data[index];
Map getDocs = data.data; 
                return ProductItem(
                  documentSnapshot: data,
                  id: data.id,
                  isFavourite: getDocs['isFavourite'],
                  imageUrl: getDocs['imageUrl'],
                  productName:getDocs['productName'],
                  productPrice: getDocs['productPrice'],
                );
              },
            );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: If it didn't work, please replace snapshot.data[index] to snapshot.data.docs[index]

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: For the record, you need to use the StreamBuilder(). In instances where there is use of the => expression, then you have to eliminate the fat operator and declare  withing the bracess of the itemBuilder {DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];}

Comment: Hey @MadhavamShahi i got the same problem in another project can't solve it can you help pleas?

Comment: Yqeah sure, could you please post your question on Stackoverflow and give me the link? @Robel

Comment: @MadhavamShahi it contains a lot of classes can i send you via email or somethin?

Comment: Okay sure, here's my email business.madhavam@gmail.com @Robel

Answer (score 8):

You are using ^0.14.0. Calling [] directly is deprecated

```
 body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return !snapshot.hasData
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return ProductItem(
                  documentSnapshot: data,
                  id: data.id,
                  isFavourite: data.data()['isFavourite'],
                  imageUrl: data.data()['imageUrl'],
                  productName: data.data()['productName'],
                  productPrice: data.data()['productPrice'],
                );
              },
            );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set data type to string for map latest firestore do this problem.

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = user.data(); 
currentUser.name = data['name'];
```

in main.dart in module widget

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                Map<String, dynamic> data = ds.data();
                print(ds);
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      data['name'],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

in model class in function use it link below

```
 List<Users> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
  return Users(
    name: data['name'] ?? '',
    email: data['email'] ?? '',
  );
}).toList();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
I think first you should create a class for your products and write a method
for parsing data that comes from api.

class Product{
   String id:
   String name;
   String quantity;

 Product({this.id,this.name,this.quantity});

   factroy Product.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => Product(
      id : json['id'],
      name : json['name'],
      quantity : json['quantity']);
   }

  Create a list of product which you wanna parse your data.
  => List<Product> products = List<Product>(); //let say home page

  make a request to api and when the condition is fine for parsing data, assing
  snapshot data to the list that we've created under State<yourWidget>.

  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
           return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: products.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Product(
              id: products[index].id,
              isFavourite: products[index].name,
              imageUrl: products[index].quantity,
            );
          },
        );
         } else {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```